# function to name range google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm very new to this so I apologize for any missing info in advance. I am trying to make a function that sets a range in any document I use it in. Here is my code at the moment:

```
function nameRangeDocDate() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Logs");

var rangeToName = sheet.setRange(1,1);
var rangeName = "DocDate";

ss.sheet.setNamedRange(rangeName, rangeToName)

}
```

Whenever I run the function I get the message: "TypeError: Cannot call method "setRange" of null. (line 6, file "we")". Can anyone explain to me what is wrong with my code? Am I missing something or is my code just wrong?

Answer (score 5):

`setNamedRange()` is a method of `Spreadsheet` class.

```
ss.sheet.setNamedRange(rangeName, rangeToName)
```

should be

```
ss.setNamedRange(rangeName, rangeToName);
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to have fixed one problem, but I'm still having trouble with others. At least I'm making progress.

Comment: sheet.setRange(1,1); should be sheet.getRange(1,1);